# How to detect reactions remove with collectors in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How to detect reactions remove with collectors in discord.js?
Looked in the discord.js docs, couple of tutorials, and still could not find it.
Any help will be great.

Comment: Could you provide some more context? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your [`ReactionCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionCollector)'s [`dispose`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/CollectorOptions) option is set to true, you can use the [`delete`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionCollector?scrollTo=e-remove) event

```js
// create your collector
const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, { dispose: true })

// event emitts when the reaction had one user removed
collector.on('remove', (reaction, user) => {
 console.log(`${user.tag} removed the reaction ${reaction.emoji.name}`);
});
```

Comment: Great, it worked amazing, thank you very much!